# Enable ADB over network without connecting device via USB

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I want to debug an application with ADB over network. I am not able to connect the device via USB to my computer, so I am looking for a way to enable ADB over network without connect it via USB. Is there an possibility?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google search : "android studio wlan adb" leads to this nice article as first result
https://betterprogramming.pub/android-wireless-debugging-using-plugin-or-adb-f2234db6b8f9#:~:text=Android%20WIFI%20ADB%20is%20a%20plugin%20available%20in,and%20debug%20your%20applications%20without%20a%20USB%20connection.

Comment: The possibilities presented on this page require an initial USB connection to enable the wireless adb connection. As described I am not able to connect the device via USB to the computer.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html
You can pair your device with android studio for debugging without USB on Android 11 and higher